# Is there any reason to use suspend fun fn(...): Either<Throwable, A> instead of suspend fun fn(...): A?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I'm mulling over something regarding `suspend` that Arrow's documentation explains in detail: `suspend () -> A` offers the same guaranties as `IO<A>`.

So, according to the documentation, just using `suspend` we are converting our impure functions into pure functions:

**Impure**

```
fun log(message: String): Unit = println(message)

fun main(): Unit { 
  log("Hey!")
}
```

**Pure**

```
suspend fun log(message: String): Unit = println(message)

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking { 
  log("Hey!")
}
```

The fact that just adding `suspend` turns the function into pure was surprising but was [clearly explained in the doc](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/effects/io/#safety--purity--referential-transparency).

Considering this, my next doubt is related to the modelling of business services that could result in an error (`Throwable`) or in a value `A`.

Up to now I was doing something like this:

```
suspend fun log(message: String): Either<Throwable, Unit> = either { println(message) }
suspend fun add(sum1: Int, sum2: Int): Either<Throwable, Int> = either { sum1 + sum2 }

suspend fun main() {
    val program = either<Throwable, Unit> {
        val sum = add(1, 2).bind()
        log("Result $sum").bind()
    }
    when(program) {
        is Either.Left -> throw program.value
        is Either.Right -> println("End")
    }
}
```

BUT, given that `suspend fun fn() : A` is pure and equivalent to `IO<A>`, we could rewrite the above program as:

```
suspend fun add(sum1: Int, sum2: Int): Int = sum1 + sum2
suspend fun log(message: String): Unit = println(message)

fun main() = runBlocking {
    try {
        val sum = add(1, 2)
        log("Result $sum")
    } catch( ex: Throwable) {
        throw ex
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to prefer `suspend fun fn(...): Either<Throwable, A>` over suspend `fun fn(...): A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to work with `Throwable` there are 2 options, `kotlin.Result` or `arrow.core.Either`.

The biggest difference is between `runCatching` and `Either.catch`. Where `runCatching` will capture *all* exceptions, and `Either.catch` will only catch [*non-fatal exceptions*](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/main/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/jvmMain/kotlin/arrow/core/NonFatal.kt#L10). So `Either.catch` will prevent you from accidentally swallowing `kotlin.coroutines.CancellationException`.

You should change the code above to the following, because `either { }` doesn't catch any exceptions.

```kotlin
suspend fun log(message: String): Either<Throwable, Unit> =
  Either.catch { println(message) }

suspend fun add(sum1: Int, sum2: Int): Either<Throwable, Int> =
  Either.catch { sum1 + sum2 }
```

> Is there any reason to prefer suspend fun fn(...): Either<Throwable, A> over suspend fun fn(...): A?

Yes, the reason to use `Result` or `Either` in the return type would be to force the caller to resolve the errors. Forcing the user to resolve an error, even within `IO<A>` or `suspend` is still valuable since `try/catch` at the end is optional.

But using `Either` becomes truly meaningful to track errors across your entire business domain. Or resolve them across layers but in a typed way.

For example:

```kotlin
data class User(...)
data class UserNotFound(val cause: Throwable?)

fun fetchUser(): Either<UserNotFound, User> = either {
  val user = Either.catch { queryOrNull("SELECT ...") }
   .mapLeft { UserNotFound(it) }
   .bind()
  ensureNotNull(user) { UserNotFound() }
}
```